# How do you insert a string or text as a blob in Cassandra (specifically CQLSH)?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I was trying to insert text or some string as a blob for testing purposes in CQLSH

```
insert into test_by_score (commit, delta, test, score)
       values (textAsBlob('bdb14fbe076f6b94444c660e36a400151f26fc6f'), 0,
       textAsBlob('{"prefix": "enwiki", "title": "\"Aghnadarragh\""}'), 100);
```

It didn't really work, because after I did:

```
select * from test_by_score where commit = 0x0b5db8b91bfdeb0a304b372dd8dda123b3fd1ab6;
```

its said there were 0 columns...which was a little unexpected (because it didn't throw an error at me) but I guess textAsBlob is not a thing in cqlsh. Then does someone know how to do this?

---

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_by_score (
    commit blob, 
    delta int, 
    score int, 
    test blob, 
    PRIMARY KEY(commit, delta, test)
);
```

I have posted my schema a little reluctantly because I believe my question is not really about this specific schema. What I simply want to to know is, if there is one column that holds blobs, is it possible to insert a string in that position by first changing it to a blob and then inserting it in cqlsh?

Comment: Could you post the CQL schema please? Are you using a program to use CQLSH to insert Blob? Or do you want to manually insert via CQLSH?

Comment: I want to manually insert the text.

Comment: My specific schema should not matter. My question is more general. I have a string and I want to transform it to a blob and insert it into a column that only holds blobs. Is that possible to do it manually?

Comment: Just to clarify, wanted schema to re-create the issue with your given queries...

Comment: don't worry, It's always good to make the question as clear as possible, no matter what, so that its as useful for me and anyone in the future. :)

Answer (score 17):

The following seems to be working. Your `WHERE` condition in your `SELECT` statement may be trying to access the incorrect hex `0x0b5db8b91bfdeb0a304b372dd8dda123b3fd1ab6`.

```
DROP KEYSPACE example;
CREATE KEYSPACE example WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1};
USE example;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_by_score (
    commit blob, -- blob representing the commit hash
    delta int, -- how much the scores have changed
    score int, -- the test score, which is determined by the client
    test blob, -- blob for the test
    PRIMARY KEY(commit, delta, test)
);

INSERT INTO test_by_score  (commit, delta, test, score) VALUES 
  (textAsBlob('bdb14fbe076f6b94444c660e36a400151f26fc6f'), 0, textAsBlob('{"prefix": "enwiki", "title": "\"Aghnadarragh\""}'), 100
);

INSERT INTO test_by_score (commit, delta, test, score) VALUES (
  textAsBlob('cdb14fbe076f6b94444c660e36a400151f26fc6f'), 0, textAsBlob('{"prefix": "enwiki", "title": "\"Aghnadarragh\""}'), 100
);

INSERT INTO test_by_score (commit, delta, test, score) VALUES (
  textAsBlob('adb14fbe076f6b94444c660e36a400151f26fc6f'), 0, textAsBlob('{"prefix": "enwiki", "title": "\"Aghnadarragh\""}'), 100
);
```

#### To grab all the rows

```
SELECT * FROM example.test_by_score
```

#### To select a specific row.

```
SELECT * FROM example.test_by_score 
  WHERE commit = 0x62646231346662653037366636623934343434633636306533366134303031353166323666633666;
```

Comment: Couldn't we use the `textAsBlob()` in the SELECT statement as well?

Comment: Yes, you can use `blobAsType(value)`, see https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/blob_r.html

Comment: @AlexisWilke no, you're gonna need `blobAsText()`