# Cassandra CQL2: Unable to update a column

Tags: cassandra

Hi i have a columnfamily in cassandra db and when i check the contents of table it is shown differently when used as

```
./cqlsh -2
select * from table1;

KEY,31281881-1bef-447a-88cf-a227dae821d6 | A,0xaa| Cidr,10.10.12.0/24 | B,0xac | C,0x01 | Ip,10.10.12.1 | D,0x00000000 | E,0xace | F,0x00000000 | G,0x7375626e657431 | H,0x666230363 | I,0x00 | J,0x353839
```

While output is as this for

```
./cqlsh -3
select * from table1;

 key                                  | Cidr          | Ip
--------------------------------------+---------------+------------
 31281881-1bef-447a-88cf-a227dae821d6 | 10.10.12.0/24 | 10.10.12.1
```

This value is inserted using java program running.

I want to suppose update value of coulmn "B" which is only seen when using -2 option manually in database, it gives me error that it is hex value.
I am using this command to update but always getting error

> cqlsh:sdnctl_db> update table1 SET B='0x7375626e657431' where key='31281881-1bef-447a-88cf-a227dae821d6';
>
> Bad Request: cannot parse '0x7375626e657431' as hex bytes
>
> cqlsh:sdnctl_db> update table1 SET B=0x7375626e657431 where key='31281881-1bef-447a-88cf-a227dae821d6';
>
> Bad Request: line 1:30 no viable alternative at input 'x7375626e657431'
>
> cqlsh:sdnctl_db> update table1 SET B=7375626e657431 where key='31281881-1bef-447a-88cf-a227dae821d6';
>
> Bad Request: line 1:37 mismatched character '6' expecting '-'

I need to insert the hex value only which will be picked by the application but not able to insert.

Kindly help me in correcting the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what data type does column B have. [Here is the reference of the CQL data types.](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html) The documentation says that `blob` data is represented as a hexadecimal string, so my assumption is that your column B is also a `blob`. From [this other cassandra question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23235573/1966937) you see how to insert strings into blobs.

```
cqlsh:so> CREATE TABLE test (a blob, b int, PRIMARY KEY (b));
cqlsh:so> INSERT INTO test(a,b) VALUES (textAsBlob('a'), 0);
cqlsh:so> SELECT * FROM test;

b | a
---+------
0 | 0x61
cqlsh:so> UPDATE test SET a = textASBlob('b') WHERE b = 0;
cqlsh:so> SELECT * FROM test;

 b | a
---+------
 0 | 0x62
```

In your case, you could convert your hex string to a char string in code, and then use the `textAsBlob` function of cqlsh.

If the data type of column B is `int` instead, why don't you convert the hex number to int before executing the insert?

Comment: These commands worked perfectly using CQL 3.0

But problem is the data i want to edit is only seen using CQL 2 or by appending '-2' option with cqlsh

suppose i now start with -2 option and check contents of test table, they ARE AS FOLLOWS

[cqlsh 2.3.0 | Cassandra 0.0.0 | CQL spec 2.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.35.0]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> use so ;
cqlsh:so> SELECT * FROM test;

 b | '\x00\x00\x00' | '\x00\x01a\x00'
---+----------------+-----------------
 0 |             0x |            0x62

Comment: now updating it and adding another coulmn as

cqlsh:so> update test set x='' where b=0;
cqlsh:so> SELECT * FROM test;

 b | '\x00\x00\x00' | '\x00\x01a\x00' | '\x00\x01x\x00'
---+----------------+-----------------+-----------------
 0 |             0x |            0x62 |              0x

But this command fails as follows

cqlsh:so> update test set x=textAsBlob('5') where b=0;
Bad Request: line 1:28 no viable alternative at input '('

cqlsh:sdnctl_db> update test set x=5 where b=0;
Bad Request: cannot parse '5' as hex bytes

Comment: The [reference for blobs in cassandra 1.2](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/blob_r.html) mentions that the `set col=0xABC123` command should work. However, several other sites say that cqlsh v2 is deprecated and that you should move to v3. I know this does not answer your question, but I cannot really test it on my machine: `cqlsh: error: '2.0.0' is not a supported CQL version.`